# Sql Server, Update with many conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have this table called `Customers`:

```
id | name | code
----------------
 1 | A    | 1
 2 | B    | 2
 3 | C    | 3
 4 | D    | 4
```

My idea is to update a list of `name` like:

```
A,B,D
```

With the value `1`, and to have:

```
id | name | code
----------------
 1 | A    | 1
 2 | B    | 1
 3 | C    | 3
 4 | D    | 1
```

How can I update `code` for a list of `name`?

I could do this:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET code=1
WHERE name='A'
OR name='B'
OR name='D';
```

But the list is big, like 45.000 names.

Is there another way to make that querie?

Comment: UPDATE ..FROM..JOIN

Comment: Where is this "list" coming from?

Comment: Is the list in a table? A file? Someone checked 45,000 checkboxes in a UI? The main problem is not going to be how to write an update, it's going to be how you pass/present 45,000 names to the statement (there are hard-coded limits in how many values can be in `IN()`, for example).

Comment: No, it's an external resource, could be a txt, a csv, etc. I have that info on an csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
UPDATE Customers
SET code=1
WHERE name IN ('A', 'B', 'D');
```

Or if you have too many records maybe something like this would be better :

```
UPDATE Customers
SET code=1
WHERE name NOT IN ('C','E');
```

Comment: Please note that SQL Server does not make any difference between `name='A' OR name='B' OR name='D'` AND `name IN ('A', 'B', 'D')`. It will change the second one into the first one before building the execution plan. By using the `NOT IN` clause, you could possibly increase performances of that query.

Comment: Thanks, I can't do it because I don't know the NOT vaues, only the values that I need to update